# Premiere Pro CC - Creating an interview video with multiple camera angles

Tags: premiere, video-editor

(edited for clarity)
I shot my first interview style video with three cameras and separate audio track. I've got all 3 video layers synced up so they are playing together but I want to switch between which layer is the top one at markers I have set on the timeline.

What is the correct way to do this? Cut all the video clips at each marker through the whole project then delete the sections I don't want visible? Use the effects panel to change opacity to zero when not in use and 100% when I want it visible?

Or is there a way to script each marker so that the program hides the layers not in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Premiere Pro has a multicam-functionality which you can use. To create a new multicam-sequence, select the three clips of your three cameras in the project panel, **right-click** → **Create Multi-Camera Source Sequence** (you might also be able to do that within your existing timeline). Then, select which synchronizing method you want to use (**audio** works just fine most of the time).

Once you click OK, it will create a new sequence that you can insert into your timeline just like any other clip or sequence. Once you've done that, click on the screwdriver icon in the programm panel and switch from **Composite Video** to **Multi-Camera**. Then, press <kbd>0</kbd> to **Toggle Multi-Cam recording** (there's also a button for that hidden behind the button editor).

Once you've done all that, you can simply playback the sequence and switch between cameras while watching (either by clicking on the different views in the program panel or using the number-keys on your keyboard as shortcuts). Premiere Pro will record the the switches and insert cuts accordingly. You can also go back and change the cuts as many times as you want.

Note that this is only one possible workflow. For some other options and more a more detailed explanation, check out the corresponding [manual page](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/create-multi-camera-source-sequence.html).

Comment: Will that also allow a simple fade to be added between each cut rather than a hard chop?

Comment: Premiere Pro inserts cuts in the Multi-Cam Sequence at every camera switch, so yes, you can apply transition effects like you would between two normals clips. Also, the Multi-Cam Sequence behaves (mostly) like a nested sequence, so you can right-click → view in timeline to edit the Multi-Cam Sequence itself if needed

Comment: Got it, thanks for your help. I got started editing in AE and while there are similarities I like the live playback in this app. Much better for this kind of work.

Comment: Yeah Premiere is better streanlined for editing tasks while AE is designed for Special Effects ... I don't get why people use AE exclusively either, IMO it's easier to use both of them to do what they were designed to do only

Comment: I'm a convert after this project. Lining up three shots in AE would have been a nightmare. I generally never need to make any heads explode or simulate light sabers so I'm going to learn Premiere.

Comment: +1. @MoritzLost I wonder if you could also read https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23287/5657 since you probably know the answer. Thanks!